# ¿Cómo implemento la declaración de una matriz la siguiente matriz inicializada?

Tags: c++, array, pair

Estoy intentando declarar un `vector < vector <pos> > path()` donde pos es un **struct** formado por dos enteros pero necesito que tenga tamaño y que este inicializado. No puedo recurrir a **typdef** ni cosas por el estilo, así que quiero hacerlo en una única linea. He intentado lo siguiente:

```
struct pos{
  int i , j ;
};

vector < vector <pos> > path (n,vector<pos>(m,pos(1,1)));
```

Pero no me compila, obtengo el siguiente error:

> **error** no matching function for call to 'pos::pos(int, int)' vector >path(n,vector(m,pos(1,1)));

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir también la declaración de `pos`?

Comment: Por favor, ¿ podrías colocar el código **exacto** que has intentado, y el error concreto que has obtenido ? Para completar la pregunta :-)

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento, ya realizaste alguna investigación previa a la pregunta. De paso te dejo los siguientes enlaces, [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878), para que mejores tu pregunta. Evita los negativos e incluso el cierre de tu pregunta y por favor mejora tus comentarios.

Comment: He intentado todas las combinaciones posibles con make_pair, usando la funcion de c++11 de ({1,1}) y otras cosas sin exito. Lo que necesito es una matriz de un tamaño n*m y que cada casilla tenga una pareja de enteros (1,1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **error** no matching function for call to 'pos::pos(int, int)' vector >path(n,vector(m,pos(1,1)));

El objeto `pos` no tiene constructor, dado que es un agregado puedes usar la inicialización de agregado:

```
vector < vector <pos> > path (n,vector<pos>(m,pos{1,1}));
//                     Llaves, no paréntesis --> ^   ^
```

También podrías añadir un constructor a `pos`:

```
struct pos{
  int i , j ;
  pos(int i, int j) : i(i), j(j) {}
};
```

Un detalle divertido de ese constructor es que los argumentos del constructor no causan ambiguedad con los miembros porque se usa la lista de inicializador del constructor. Recuerda que si le añades un constructor con parámetros, el objeto `pos` deja de ser construible por defecto, te aconsejo cambiarlo de esta manera:

```
struct pos{
  int i{} , j{} ;
  pos() = default;
  pos(int i, int j) : i(i), j(j) {}
};
```

Al añadir las llaves a las variables miembro, éstas se inicializarán por defecto, y al marcar el constructor sin parámetros como `default` dejarás que el compilador lo redacte por ti.

Comment: La respuesta no se guardó bien. Ahora esta bien escrita lo siento

Comment: Yo veo la respuesta perfectamente.

Comment: La pregunta, perdon

Comment: ¿Esta respuesta no responde tu pregunta?

Comment: No, porque no quiero hacerlo en un vector. Tengo un vector de vectores de structs, y dicho struct es una pareja de enteros

Comment: joder, que no me cambieis la pregunta que se lo que estoy preguntando. Menudo sitio es este

Comment: Entonces no coincide el título de la pregunta con lo que necesitas ni con lo que pones como ejemplo; te aconsejo editar la pregunta (título incluido) para dar detalles más relevantes.

Comment: Pero vamos a ver. La pregunta es sencilla y clara. Que tu no la entiendas es otra cosa.

Comment: No: la pregunta ni es sencilla ni es clara. 1) hablas de un pair en el título y no hay ningún pair en tu código 2) mencionas una matriz en tu título y no hay ninguna matriz en tu código 3) hablas de un error de compilación pero no das detalles del mismo 4) impones limitaciones al uso de utilidades de C++ pero no explicas por qué. Por favor, edita tu pregunta para dar detalles más relevantes, **ayudanos a ayudarte**.

Comment: A vale, vale ahora ya lo veo. Claro. Le falta el constructor y muchas otras cosas. Es que esto forma parte de un gran programa pero queria implementar un BFS aparte para asegurarme de que funcionaba correctamente y no tuve en cuenta que no habia hecho la misma implementacion del struct que la que hay en el programa original. Al final, como que este era de prueba, lo he hecho en typedef y despues al pasarlo solo tengo que cambiarlo los .first y .second y ya esta. muchas gracias